# How do I permanently delete my photos

Tags: lumia

I have a Nokia Lumia 520 phone and when I take pictures or save pictures from the web they are stored in camera roll and saved pictures. Sometimes I delete photos from those albums, but still see the deleted photos in camera roll hotmail and saved pictures hotmail. How can I delete these pictures permanently that they cannot be recovered?

Answer (score 1):

If you have signed into your Windows Phone using your Microsoft account then the photos you are seeing are probably those backed up on OneDrive. If that's the case then whenever you delete photos you absolutely don't want consider deleting them off your OneDrive if they exist their also.